# Why do library functions not need to qualified with std::?

Tags: c++

In C++, when referencing identifiers declared in the standard namespace, these identifiers need to be qualified with "std::" (name of namespace + scope resolution operator). However, my program compiles without error even if I don't qualify identifiers of functions.

For instance, the following code compiles without error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s); // works.
    getline(std::cin, s); // also works. Why?
}
```

Running `g++ --version` outputs the following:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Why is the second last line in the sample code above correct? Does it work for all compilers/environments?

Comment: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: If not for ADL, you might have to do `std::string a{"alpha"}, b{"beta"}; auto s = std::operator+(a, b);` which some people might find inconvenient.